# Jquery showing once after submit

Tags: php, jquery, html

I made this form and added some jquery to it. The jquery part is supposed to make a div show if i click on submit. 
It does this but only once the it refreshes the page and the div goes back to hidden. I have everything in the same file the jquery and the php and the html.
How do i make the jquery stay.

```
<form class ="form" method="post">
    <h3>Select your trademark</h3>
        <select class="form-control" name="trademark">
            <option></option>
            <option>©</option>
            <option>™</option>
            <option>®</option>
        </select>

    <h3>Your company name</h3>
    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="companyName" action="">

        <br/>
        <br/>

    <button class="form-control" type="submit" name="submit">
        Generate
    </button>
</form>

<script>
    $("button.form-control").click(function(){
        $(".codes").show();
    });
</script>
```

EDIT:

Tried prevent default with Jquery it works it doesnt reload but it doesnt post the filled in data from form in my page.

Comment: A submit button submits the form, as it should

Comment: What exactly is that button suppose to do? You have set a click-event in jQuery AND you have an "onclick" on the button. (Btw... the onclick: `onclick="loadDoc"()` should be `onclick="loadDoc()"`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `onsbumit="return false"` to your `<form>`. By returning `false` from the `onsubmit` handler you prevent the form from being submitted (no further requests are sent to the server, and the page is not reloaded).

Comment: @KevinAartsen, you have tried `preventDefault`. What about my version, have you tried to add the `onsubmit` attribute?

Answer (score 2):

Because the button you are pressing is `type="submit"` it is running your javascript and submitting the form as well

There is a javascript function that will stop the default submit action `preventDefault()`

```
<script>
    $("button.form-control").click(function(event){
//------------------------------------------^^^^^
        event.preventDefault();
        $(".codes").show();
    });
</script>
```

Alternatively you could remove `type="submit"` from the button attributes.

EDIT:

Also this is wrong

```
onclick="loadDoc"()
```

should be

```
onclick="loadDoc()"
```

Comment: Now I am confused? What do you want to happen??

Answer (score 2):

Your button is a submit button, which means that after your JS onclick finishes, the form submits as usual. You have to prevent that:

```
$("button.form-control").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    etc...
```

Answer (score 0):

NOTE1: Load jquery Library

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Try this:

`<input class="form-control" id="generateButton" type="button" value="Generate" name="submit" onclick="loadDoc()">`

instead your button code.

Modify the jquery code:
`<script>` 
`$(document).ready(function() {`
        `$("#generateButton").click(function(event){`
         `event.preventDefault();`
         `$(".codes").show();`
      `});`
`});//DOM`
`</script>`

NOTE: The #id selector is much faster then your code.
NOTE 2: if you want the loadDoc() function can be inserted inside the jquery click function....